# How to output checkboxes from an HTML form by PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

**I have an HTML form as:**

```
<form action="something.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="color">
<fieldset>
    <legend><h2><span style="color: #993300; text-shadow: #808080 2px 1px 2px; font-size: 25px;">Color Preferences:</span></h2></legend>&nbsp;
    <p><table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="350px;"><span style="color: #993300;">*</span> Colors you consider to use to your new Site:</td>
                <td>
                                  <br/> 
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Black" /> Black<br/> 
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Blue" /> Blue<br/> 
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Brown" /> Brown<br/> 
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Gray" /> Gray<br/> 
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Green" /> Green<br/> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></p>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
```

**To execute the color form, I used a PHP as:**

```
$color = $_POST['color'];    
if (!isset($color))
       {
        unset($_GET['do']);
         $message = "Error = Colors are required. Please try again.";
         break;
         } else {
         $N = count($color);
         for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++){
         echo($color[$i] . " ");
         }
       }
```

But when I test my code over the output area it only giving an "Array" as a result.
Can you please help me to fix this code?
(I need to get the selected colors as an output instead of "Array".)

I even changed my codes into:

```
$color = $_POST['color'] && $_POST['color'] = array ('Black','Blue','Brown','Gray','Green','Orange','Pink','Purple','Red','Silver','Tan','White','Yellow','Dark','Light');
            if (!isset($_POST['color'])) 
            {
                unset($_GET['do']);
                echo "Error = Colors are required. Please try again.";
            } else {
                $n = count($_POST['color']);
                echo("You selected $n color(s): ");
                for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
                {
                    echo($_POST['color'][$i] . " ");
                }
            }
```

but still the result outcome is only "Array" instead of colors name. can you please help me to resolve this issue?

---

I even changed my codes into:

```
$color = $_POST['color'] && $_POST['color'] = array ('Black','Blue','Brown','Gray','Green','Orange','Pink','Purple','Red','Silver','Tan','White','Yellow','Dark','Light');
            if (!isset($_POST['color'])) 
            {
                unset($_GET['do']);
                echo "Error = Colors are required. Please try again.";
            } else {
                $n = count($_POST['color']);
                echo("You selected $n color(s): ");
                for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
                {
                    echo($_POST['color'][$i] . " ");
                }
            }
```

but still the result outcome is only "Array" instead of colors name. can you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try print_r($color[$i]); to print the structure. This might help you with your problem.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. The problem you have is $color is always set, not matter if $_POST['color'] is recieved. You should test `if(!isset($_POST['color']))` instead of $color, and in the else statement to assign $color to the posted value

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST['color']);`

Answer (score 0):

with color[], you will receive an array ($_POST['color']). You can test if it is isset() or it is empty()

if it is NOT empty, then you can iterate over the values for instance like this:

```
$n = count($_POST['color']);
echo("You selected $n color(s): ");
for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
  echo($_POST['color'][$i] . " ");
}
```

(untested. Code taken from here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html)

Comment: He's doing the same, and the code is actually working, except testing for isset()

Comment: You're right.. I was irritated by "Array" as a result. Sorry for the misleading answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

PHP Code:

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
        if (!isset($_POST['color'])) {
            unset($_GET['do']);
            echo "Error = Colors are required. Please try again.";
        } else {
            $color = $_POST['color'];
            $N = count($color);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
                echo($color[$i] . " ");
            }
        }
    }
```