# How to input value from buttons and checkboxes to textarea

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have looked around on the site, but I haven't found much of anything of what I want. Anyway, I am a self taught HTML/CSS person. Most of my experience is in using Wordpress, but anyhow, I am trying create a interactive site (not in wordpress unfortunately) that uses forms to create an output of a huge set of code.

```
<form id="drawing">
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="normal">Normal<br />
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="custom">Custom<br />
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Print Code"><br />

<textarea></textarea>
```

I want to print the value taken from the radio buttons into the textarea like this: drawtype = (value here),

So what would be the easiest, lighter-weight way to go about this? I have seen this topic: [How to output checkboxes from an HTML form by PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297004/how-to-output-checkboxes-from-an-html-form-by-php) but is there a simpler way to do it? I have not had much experience with php at all, so that is why I'm asking this. If there is another answer that I didn't notice then it would be nice to be redirected to it. (especially since this is my first question.)

Thanks.

Comment: You could probably try `<textarea><?php echo $_POST['draw']; ?></textarea>` or use an `isset` ternary operator.

Comment: If you don't need the information on the server just yet, you should use javascript, no need to post if you are not going to store it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidenote: Your `<input type="submit" value="Print Code"><br />`  is presently outside the `<form></form>` tags, so it won't execute.

A Basic sample: (all in one file example)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$draw = $_POST['draw'];
}
?>

<form id="drawing" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="normal">Normal<br />
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="custom">Custom<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print Code"><br />
</form>

<textarea><?php echo $_POST['draw']; ?></textarea>
```

Slightly different method:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) || !empty($_POST['draw'])){
if(empty($_POST['draw'])){
echo "Make a selection.";
   }
$draw= $_POST['draw'];
   }
?>

<form id="drawing" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="normal">Normal<br />
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="custom">Custom<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print Code"><br />
</form>

<textarea><?php echo $_POST['draw']; ?></textarea>
```

---

### EDIT

Here is a jQuery method, yet I'm not sure if this is the desired effect:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$draw = $_POST['draw'];
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var player = "<?php echo $_POST['draw']; ?>";

// alert (player);
    });
</script>

Your choice: <span id='draw'><?php echo $_POST['draw']?></span></div>


<form id="drawing" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="normal">Normal<br />
<input type="radio" name="draw" value="custom">Custom<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Print Code"><br />
</form>

<textarea><?php echo $_POST['draw']; ?></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

If selecting `normal`, the source for the script would appear as:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
var player = "normal";

// alert (player);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. So is there a way to do it using jquery or vanilla javascript? Just asking.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure there is a way, but my jQuery skills are not very good, to be honest with you. @WisdomFire - I might have something in my libraries in using plain JS, but not jQuery and it uses sessions, so not entirely sure it would work with this.

Comment: Reload my answer and look under the **EDIT**. Am not sure if that's what you were thinking of, but that's what I came up with. I borrowed it from a "session-based" script that I had. @WisdomFire

Comment: Ok, so I have tried using the small bit of code you gave me, but all I'm getting is the exact words <?php echo $_POST['draw']; ?> in the textarea. ??? I'm sorry, I only really know the skeletal basics of php, nothing special at all.

Comment: Did you name your files with a `.php` or `.html` extension? @WisdomFire - 99% of the time, that's what the issue is.

Comment: I just put the code in the html page in front of the rest of the code. This is the way I put it in index.html  <body> ... <?php ... ?> <form ...> then the rest form in the index.html.  I'm sorry, but it that incorrect?

Comment: it needs to be called `index.php` not `.html` in order for it to work. @WisdomFire

Comment: I tried that, and it still isn't working. I am apparently in the 1%.